# Issues with getting file information in subfolders

Tags: python, gitlab

I have some issues with getting file information in subfolders. My python application gathers information from GitLab project files en subfolders, but when I try to open a file in the subfolder is shows me an error 404.

[image: This is what I already have:]

I simply think that the application only gathers subfolder information and not from the files inside. So I can navigate.

Comment: Please post the code as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.